# updating Google map location by passing latlong with constructor throwing null point exception android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using google maps v2 with actionbar tab fragment. everything is works fine but i need to update my maps location by passing lat long from first tab (first fragment) as map is on second tab. I am passing latlong via constructor. 
firstly the problem was handling the lifecycle of fragment on viewpager, but by following [this](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/viewpager-with-detailed-fragment-lifecycle-onresumefragment-including-source-code/) tutorial the problem was solved. now i am using map updation method in "onFragmentPause" but it is throwing null point exception still it works fine if i place it in "onViewCreate()" code showing in details.

**Tracking fragment:**

```
public class Track extends Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle {
private static GoogleMap mMap;
private static Double latitude, longitude;
private static String vAddress;
private static View Track;
DataHandler dh;

@Override 
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if(activity instanceof DataHandler)
    {
        dh = (DataHandler)activity;
    }
    else
        throw new ClassCastException();

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    Track  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_track, container, false);

    return Track;
}

public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();
        setUpMap();
}

private static void setUpMap() {
    try{
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(vAddress).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker2)));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,
            longitude), 12.0f));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.wtf("this error", "ok");
    }
}

public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();

    try {
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map));  
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void onPauseFragment() {

}
@Override
public void onResumeFragment() {
    Log.i("state", "onResumeFragment()");
    latitude= 73.023333; //getting latitude from first tab(fragment)by calling constructor 
    longitude= 67.939322;
    vAddress = "some address";
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
```

now if i place setUpMapIfNeeded() in onCreateView and change the rotation, it recreate and update the location but error when put in onResumeFragment().
kindly help me out and sorry if i could not describe effectively.

**Error**
since logcat shows the error at line 48. that is
     .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();

this is **Activity_Track**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
         <fragment
        android:id="@+id/location_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If i change from static values to this it crashes a give null point exception at line latitude= dh.getLat();

```
@Override
    public void onResumeFragment() {
        Log.i("state", "onResumeFragment()");
        latitude= dh.getLat(); //getting latitude from first tab(fragment)by calling constructor 
        longitude= dh.getLong();
        vAddress = dh.getAddress();
        setUpMap();
    }
```

Comment: datahandler is null because it was garbage collected you need to store your data elsewhere

Comment: in other case if i give latlong statically it again give the same error. so this is not the prob i my case atleast.

Comment: then what line is the error happening on

Comment: 01-28 18:34:51.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 18:34:51.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1710): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-28 18:34:51.146: E/AndroidRuntime(1710):  at com.upanels.edrivetrackingapp.Track.onResumeFragment(Track.java:83)
@tyczj plz check

Comment: that does not tell me what is on the line that is causing the problem

Comment: when onResumeFragment() method called.

Comment: if i do all the stuff in onCreateView rather then in onResumeFragment(), than everything works fine but it does not update marker location run time. even log shows the onResumeMethod called. :(

Comment: WHAT IS ON THAT LINE!!!

Comment: @tyczj did u get it?

Comment: dear lord line `83` has code on it WHAT IS THAT CODE!!

Comment: for convenience i changed lil bit
latitude = 73.0909;
lonitude = 67.0099;
address = "some address";
setUpMapIfNeeded();
now this line setUpMapIfNeeded() is error.

Comment: You should put the `setUpMapIfNeed()` in `onCreateView()` method, and put the `setUpMap()` in the `onResumeFragment()` method, so the your map can still update.

Comment: Please post your activity_track.xml layout file.  It's hard for anyone to figure out what your problem is without you providing more detail.

Comment: @ztan thanks you so much, it resolved my prob but still, if i add latlong and address dynamically, it crashes again. I am passing values by constructor from first fragment.

Comment: Thanks all for your response. i solved my problem :)